# Create a global available array by the size of an updown

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a static global array called "series". But the number of strings inside it should depend on a nummericUpDown counter. I have tried a lot of variations, resulting in a lot of error variations. My code looks like this, near the top of my code i have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static string[] series;
```

So after i have made the array global with that i want to set its size.
As a nummericUpDown can go up and down, i erase array first (causing errors)
Later i want to fill it with   { "M1","M2","M3" ......etc}
How should i write this code that it will work ?

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numericUpDown1.Value < 1) { numericUpDown1.Value = 1; }
        int i;
        series[0] = "x";

        if (series.Length > 0) { Array.Clear(series, 0, series.Length); }
        for (i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++) { series[i] = "M" + i.ToString(); }

    }
```

Comment: Do you **have to** use an array? Can you not just use a `List<string>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set your series variable to a new array of the correct size.  Doing so will clear all previous values that were in the array before.

```
if (series.Length > 0) { series = new string[numericUpDown1.Value]; }
```

Comment: i rewrote it

    if (numericUpDown1.Value < 1) { numericUpDown1.Value = 1; }
            series = new string[Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value)]; 
            int j=series.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { series[i] = "M" + i.ToString(); }

Answer (score 0):

A `List<string>` would be a much better idea. But if you really have to use an array:

I would suggest that you define the array initially as:
    static string[] series = new string[0];

Then, if the up/down changes:

```
Array.Resize(ref series, newSize);
```

This will allow re-sizing an existing array. Note, however, that if the size decreases, you'll lose data.

Answer (score 0):

hi rewrote it now like this and it works, thanks for you answer!

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       if (numericUpDown1.Value < 1) { numericUpDown1.Value = 1; }
        series = new string[Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value)]; 
        int j=series.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { series[i] = "M" + i.ToString(); }
}
```